# Specify Failover Partner with SQL Alchemy and pymssql

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, failover, pymssql

Does anyone know how to connect to connect to a SQL Server from `SQL Alchemy` and `pymssql` specifying `Failover Partner`? Trying to follow the [SQL Alchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pymssql) but cannot find failover option.

How can I add `Failover Partner=myfailover;Initial Catalog=mydb` to this code?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
conn_str = "mssql+pymssql://{user}:{pwd}@{host}/{db}".format(host=SERVER, db=DATABASE, user=USERNAME, pwd=PASSWORD)
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation it doesn't support failover in the API.

Instead you could try adding a try and except block.

```
try:
     #connect to first partner
except:
      # connect to failover
```